# How to show data from a database in my table from my website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop

I have a database that I want to access to display my product data, in this case the ItemCode and ItemName.
the connections are all correct and the functional, my problems is the loop and show the data in the table that I have in the html file.

```js
let ctrl = {
      showDados: function(r) {
    
     /*dados[3].ItemCode;*/ 
      
       let dados = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
       let cod = dados.ItemCode;
       let name = dados.ItemName;
       let text = "";
       let i;
    
       for (i = 0; i < cod.length; i++) {
        text += cod[i] + "<br>";
       }
                               document.getElementById("cod").innerHTML = text;
    
       for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        text += name[i] + "<br>";
       }
       document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text; 
    
     },
    
     init: function() {
      util.ajax(settings.serviceAddress + "OITM", ctrl.showDados);
     }
};
    
$(document).ready(function() {
  ctrl.init();
});
```

```html
<div class="container">      
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td id="cod">FSE0204</td>
        <td id="name">25130101_Loc.Finaneira - BCP- CT 400105814</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>FSE0205</td>
        <td>25130201_Loc.Finaneira - Totta- CT 195649</td>
        </tr>   
      </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  ctrl.init();
}); 
 You didn't include jquery in your script tags
 I don't think you use it so replace $(document).ready by window.onload = ...

Comment: If your ajx request works then simplify the problem by providing a "mock" ie a json string to parse or even an object or array of objects and use it to build your table

Comment: Where is util declared?  If I add jQuery I get an error on the util statement in the init function.